# Python regex to replace a Particular line in paragraphs as per regex only not whole file

Tags: python, regex, replace, regexp-replace

```
s="""Paragraph 1
some text blah blah
blah blah
UNWANTED TEXT
some text
Paragraph END

UNWNTED TEXT

Paragraph 2
some text blah blah
blah blah
UNWNTED TEXT
Paragraph END"""
```

Now python code to re.sub to replace UNWANTED TEXT only inside paragraphs keep UNWANTED TEXT Outside paragraphs

```
search_unwanted_only_inparagrap = re.findall('(?s)(?<=Paragraph)(.*?)(?=END)', text_file, flags = re.MULTILINE )
if search_unwanted_only_inparagrap:
    replace_only_insidepara = re.sub(r"UNWANTED TEXT+", " ", text_file)   #replace string substitue
    print (replace_only_insidepara)
else:
    print ("not found")
```

But the output replace all instance of UNWANTED TEXT in through out the file

```
Paragraph 1
some text blah blah
blah blah

some text
Paragraph END



Paragraph 2
some text blah blah
blah blah

Paragraph END
```

but i expect like this

```
Paragraph 1
some text blah blah
blah blah

some text
Paragraph END

UNWNTED TEXT

Paragraph 2
some text blah blah
blah blah

Paragraph END
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your demo input should have been more 'minimal'. However, I tried to understand your requirement and I tried re.split works:

```
import re

s = """Paragraph 1
some text blah blah
blah blah
UNWANTED TEXT
some text
Paragraph END

UNWANTED TEXT

Paragraph 2
some text blah blah
blah blah
UNWANTED TEXT
Paragraph END"""
reg_para = re.compile(r'(Paragraph\s+\d+.+?END)', re.DOTALL)
paras = reg_para.split(s)
for para in paras:
    if reg_para.match(para):
        para = re.sub(r"UNWANTED TEXT", " ", para)
        #  in case you want replace more words:
        #  of course you can use list of keywords some loops
        para = re.sub(r"Another WORD", " ", para)
        print(para)
    else:
        print(para)
```

Output:

```sh
Paragraph 1
some text blah blah
blah blah
 
some text
Paragraph END


UNWANTED TEXT


Paragraph 2
some text blah blah
blah blah
 
Paragraph END
```

Comment: You are awesome. Solved my issue i am struggling for last 2 days. Thanks a lot for your valuable time and love.

Comment: One additional query can we have multiple pattern in re.sub ```removed = re.sub(r"UNWANTED TEXT", " ", para)```  for all the pattern its blank replacement only. Like ```removed = re.sub(r"UNWANTED TEXT", "Another WORD", " ", para)```. I have used dict key value pair for whole text file but for this regex pattern need some simple solution. Thanks.